# previewsContainer and clickable options not working in dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I need to move the drop/clickable and previews area from `<form>` to a separated div container, so I can use a normal form.

The problem is that I set those two options but nothing happens, it still shows the whole form as the area (in jsfiddle at least is clickable but in my page is not).

This is the html code I'm using (yes, dropzone is a css class with styles):

```
<form id="myAwesomeDropzone" class="dropzone" action="index.php">
    <div class="option img">
        <p>Imagenes (máximo 6):</p>
        <div id="dropzone">
            <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    // more form
</form>
```

And this is the dropzone code:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName: "file",
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    parallelUploads: 6,
    maxFilesize: 6,
    maxFiles: 6,
    autoDiscover: false,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    previewsContainer: '.dropzone-previews',
    clickable: '.dropzone-previews',

    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;

    // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
    this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    myDropzone.processQueue();
    });

    // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
    // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
    this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
    // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
    // Hide the success button or the complete form.
    });
    this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
    // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
    // Redirect user or notify of success.
    alert(response);
    });
    this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
    // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
    // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
    alert(response);
    });
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/enr8jg3o/1/

Answer (score 0):

the HTML you wrote, do what It should.also it only move the place of File icons(previews) and clickable area to that new div, but I don`t think there was an option in Dropzone.js to move the dropable area.
Bythewhy , you can use normal form without that div.